# "He thinks it is/were/would be a smart thing to do"

Tags: word-usage

> - He thinks it **is** a smart thing to do.
> - He thinks it **were** a smart thing to do.
> - He thinks it **would be** a smart thing to do.

Are all of them possible? And again which is the preferred choice when talking about something he considers a smart thing to do?

Comment: Using present indicative "he thinks", you would say: He thinks ***it is/would be*** a smart thing to do.

Comment: Okay thanks and in which scenario would the subjunctive make sense?

Comment: The use of conditional suggests that you are  considering  the pros  and cons and that you think that it may be a smart course of action.

Comment: The subjunctive would be revealed in a dependent clause such as: _"He would do it **if it were the smart thing to do.**"_ It requires an action or state that is unknown to the speaker at the time of speaking. (There is no subjunctive in any of your examples.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He thinks it is a smart thing to do.
>
> He thinks it were a smart thing to do.
>
> He thinks it would be a smart thing to do.

The first is a simple statement "A is B".

The second is incomplete, since the *were* construction is usually part of a "if-then" conditional:

> He thinks **if** it were a smart thing to do ... (everyone would do it).

The third is implicitly incomplete, since *would* is used in hypothetical sentences, usually with an "if" conditional:

> He thinks it would be a smart thing to do (if he only had the time)

It's not absolutely *necessary* to explicitly state the condition where it is true, but by using "would" you do imply that there is *some* condition.

As with anything, which you choose to use depends on what you want to say.

> I think you will vote in the election.
>
> I think, if you were to vote in the election, it would be good.
>
> I think you would vote in the election, if you thought it was a good thing to do.